json date format to YYYY-MM-DD from 2001-09-10T21:00:00.000Z
i got this json file
    {
    other arguments
      "releaseYear": "9/11/2001",
     other arguments
  
    },

the releaseYear argument is formmated like that in the front-end 2001-09-10T21:00:00.000Z and i want it be like that 2001-09-10 and i got an input type date and got the same formmat as the first one and want it be like YYYY-MM-DD
trying to fix this date formmat

I think you’re asking Joe to format a date in JavaScript? I’d try searching the web/etc first maybe and see if that helps.

Maybe you're looking for something like this, but the question is currently unclear. You can edit it to provide additional detail.

the thing you're trying to do here can easily be solved via packages like dayJS or momentJS.

Install momentJS in your project using npm install moment --save or yarn add moment (based on your project npm/yarn)
Use it like moment(releaseYear).format('YYYY MM DD');

For extensive formatting guide, read here: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/
